# Where I can find the implementation of Autowired Annotation in Spring?

Tags: spring

I want to implement my own custom annotations, that is why I am looking for Spring annotations' implementation. Which code executes behind the screen when we use an annotation?

Answer (score 1):

Definition of an annotation is pretty simple. You can find definition of `@Autowired` annotation here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.java

If you're interested in its processing, you can clone `spring-framework` repository and search for its usage in the code of Spring.

If you want to implement your own custom annotation processor, I'd recommend to search for simpler examples than Spring and `@Autowired`.

I'm also planning to play around with annotation processors and I collected a few links related to this topic. Maybe you'll find them useful.

Java related:

- https://github.com/bozaro/example-annotation-processor
- https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/annotations
- http://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder
- https://www.gesellix.net/post/providedcompile-and-compile-dependencies-with-gradle/
- http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/playing-with-java-annotation-processing.html
- https://github.com/Jimdo/gradle-apt-plugin
- http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2016/03/gradle-goodness-enable-compiler.html
- https://github.com/sockeqwe/annotationprocessing101
- http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101
- https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/java-annotation-processors.html

and bonuses

Android related:

- https://medium.com/@iammert/annotation-processing-dont-repeat-yourself-generate-your-code-8425e60c6657
- https://stablekernel.com/the-10-step-guide-to-annotation-processing-in-android-studio/
- https://medium.com/@emmasuzuki/annotation-processor-101-your-first-custom-annotation-a3db9ae48046
- http://blog.jensdriller.com/android-annotation-processing-setup-using-gradle/

Kotlin related:

- https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/06/better-annotation-processing-supporting-stubs-in-kapt/